# PaintComponent function keeps being run

Tags: java, paintcomponent

Somehow, I've managed to break a pretty simple part of my application. I've created a panel that shows boxes, which are filled with products by an algorithm. This is to solve the Bin Packing Problem. Under each box is a little text, "Contents..." which on hover will show the setToolTipText which contains with how much % the box is filled. However...

...Everytime I click on them, the paintComponent function just runs again. This while there is literally not a single mouse event and I just can't figure out WHY it's happening.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        try {
            if (packedBoxes != null || packedBoxes.size() != 0) {
                drawboxWidth = (getWidth() / packedBoxes.size()) - (100 / packedBoxes.size()) - 5;
                drawboxHeight = (getHeight() / 2);

                //drawing products
                for (int i = 0; i < packedBoxes.size(); i++) {

                    int x = 50 + (drawboxWidth * i) + (i * 5);
                    int currentY = 50;

                    for (Item item : packedBoxes.get(i).getItems()) {
                        float productHeight = (float) item.height / (float) boxHeight;
                        float drawProductHeight = drawboxHeight * productHeight;
                        g.setColor(item.color);
                        g.fillRect(x, currentY, drawboxWidth, (int) drawProductHeight);
                        currentY += drawProductHeight;
                    }

                    int y = 50;
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g.drawRect(x, y, drawboxWidth, drawboxHeight);

                    boxLabels.add(new JLabel("Contents.."));
                    boxInfo.add("<html><font face=\"sansserif\"><h2>Box nr."+(i+1)+"</h2>" +
                            "Percentage filled: "+(int)(((float)packedBoxes.get(i).getUsedSize()/(float) boxHeight)*100)+ "% \n</html>");
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < boxLabels.size(); i++) {

                    int x = 50 + (drawboxWidth * i) + (i * 5);
                    int y = drawboxHeight + 100;

                    boxLabels.get(i).setBounds(x, y, drawboxWidth, 20);
                    boxLabels.get(i).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    boxLabels.get(i).setToolTipText(boxInfo.get(i));
                    this.add(boxLabels.get(i));
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            //ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Is there any logical reason why this happens? This causes the boxLabels arraylist to fill up everytime, meaning that boxLabels.size() is also increased by the amount of boxes every single time.

Any help is appreciated, I really have no idea anymore;p

Comment: I don't understand, a click is a mouse event...

Comment: @RobinGreen Precisely, this is exactly why I have no idea why it's being run since there is no mouse event xd

Comment: But a click IS a mouse event, and you said YOU CLICKED ON THEM. So there IS a mouse event.